# Random occurence of javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

Tags: java, ssl, https

During the execution of My java code i get the this error message

```
Exception in thread "main" AxisFault  faultCode:
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
faultSubcode:   faultString: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
faultActor:   faultNode:
faultDetail: 
{http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?    at
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(InputRecord.java:523) at
 com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:355) at
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:830)   at
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1170) at
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1197)  at
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1181)  at
org.apache.axis.components.net.JSSESocketFactory.create(JSSESocketFactory.java:186) at
org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.getSocket(HTTPSender.java:191)    at
org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.writeToSocket(HTTPSender.java:404)    at
org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:138) at
org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32) at
org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)    at
org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)     at
org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)   at
org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2765)    at
org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2748)  at
org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2424)  at
org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2347)  at
org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1804)  at
crmondemand.ws.ecbs.customobject5.CustomObject5_BindingStub.customObject5Update(CustomObject5_BindingStub.java:301) at
crm.sapGUID.urlupdate(sapGUID.java:170)     at
 crm.sapGUID.readExcelFile(sapGUID.java:102)    at
 crm.sapGUID.main(sapGUID.java:218)
```

The occurence of this error is random everytime i re-run my program.Sometimes after 10 mins, sometimes after 8 mins, sumtime after 1 min to sumtime even after 15 mins.

I am behind proxy and have hardcoded the same proxy setting in my JAVA as in my Internt Explorer as

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "172.*.*.*");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8003");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/cacerts");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you are using `System.setProperty()` ... and if something else in the same JVM is calling the same System.setProperty() it will override your setting.  Your best shot here is to use:

```
InetSocketAddress proxyInet = new InetSocketAddress("172...*",8003);
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, proxyInet);
```

The `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` might be ok, since it is passing in through -D option from the command line and rarely change and so, I don't think you need to set it in your code.  At least if you need it, set it in a `static {}` block so it will only be loaded one, no need for repeat setting.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are always running this with the same URL, you are doing exactly what it says in the exception: using SSL to connect to a plaintext port. Occasionally.

Answer (score 0):

set environment variable

```
_JAVA_OPTIONS = -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

This solved my issue.If you are on company's private network, give it a try.